# SELECT old data state with DB2

Tags: select, db2

Is it possible to access old data state in an DB2 database?

Oracle has the clause

```
select ... as of timestamp
```

to do it. Does DB2 have something like it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can select a set of rows that were / will be valid in a past / future time. This is called Time Travel in DB2, but you have to configure / create the table with the extra columns in order to activate this feature. This is new in DB2 10, but I think it is not available in all editions.

For more information, take a look at this: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1204db2temporaldata/

Remember, there are two concepts: business time and application time, and when using both is called bi-temporal.

Comment: SELECT coverage_amt 
FROM policy FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF '2010-12-01' 
WHERE id = 1111;